# Is there a command (and ideally a key binding) to navigate to the top (or bottom) of an org table?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-table, navigation

I have read [Built-in Table Editor](https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-Table-Editor.html), and searched `apropos-function org table` for `top`, `bottom`, `beginning`, and `end`. I found `org-table-beginning-of-field`, but not anything like `org-table-beginning-of-table`.

`M-{` is bound to `org-backward-element`, so inside a table it doesn't go back a paragraph but just a line.

`C-M-a` is still bound in `org-mode` to `beginning-of-defun`, which inside a table just goes up one line.

Is there some standard text-mode key binding that gets you to the top of the table that I haven't thought of trying yet? There must already be a way to do this?

Comment: You probably don't have enough reputation yet, but  instead of editing your question to add an answer, you can submit an edit to the answer (or you can submit - and accept - your own answer). That makes it easier for future visitors to figure out what's the question and what's the answer. It is also important that when an answer *does* answer your question that you *accept* it, thereby indicating to the aforesaid future visitors that the question has been answered to your satisfaction. See [What should I do when somebody answers?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: You are correct about my not having enough reputation -- I couldn't even upvote your answer yesterday. I had no idea that that askers could edit answers until you just told me about that. I'll read the link you shared. But I also wanted to wait a bit before accepting an answer in case someone happens by who knows of a vanilla text-mode Emacs navigation keystroke that has the effect I desire.

Comment: Waiting a bit for an answer is actually a good idea. The main thing that I would like to avoid is having an answer *in* the question. But reading the link (and browsing through the rest of the Help - click the icon with the question mark in the upper right of any quesition) is highly recommended.

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of, but Org mode provides the ingredients to roll your own easily:

```el
(defun org-table-goto-beginning ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (org-table-begin)))

(defun org-table-goto-end ()
   (interactive)
   (goto-char (org-table-end)))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c t b") #'org-table-goto-beginning)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c t e") #'org-table-goto-end)
```

Both of these assume that when they are called, `point` is within a table. Both could probably use some error handling if that is not the case.